# Alternating Recurrence relation $a_n = b_{n-1} + 5$ and $b_n = na_{n-1}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

I am racking my brain on solving the relation where:

$$a_n = b_{n-1} + 5$$
$$b_n = na_{n-1}$$

where $a_0$ = $b_0$ = 1

I am trying to find the closed form for $a_n$.  I have tried to shifting $b_n = na_{n-1}$ to $b_{n-1} = (n-1)a_{n-2}$ by substituting n with n-1.  Then I plug $b_{n-1}$ in to $a_n = b_{n-1} + 5$ to get $a_n = (n-1)a_{n-2} + 5$

I am trying to use the method of generating functions to do this.  I have that $A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}$.  Now I move to the n = 3 term of the summand and get $1+6x+6x^2 + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}$ as $a_0 = 1, a_1 = a_2 = 6$ Then we substitute in the relation to get $1+6x+6x^2 + x^2\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} ((n-1)a_{n-2}+5)x^{n-2}$ = $1+6x+6x^2 + x^2\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (n-1)a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}5x^{n-2}$
I know what to do with the latter term as $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}5x^{n-2} = 5x/(1-x)$.  I however am not sure what to do with the $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (n-1)a_{n-2}x^{n-2}$ term as there is an (n-1) in it.  I do however see that $(n-1)a_{n-2}x^{n-2}$ looks like it could be integrated with respect to x to become $a_{n-2}x^{n-1}$.  If I then pull out a x I could end up with:

$1+6x+6x^2 + x^3/(1-x)+ 5x/(1-x)$

But I am first shaky on how I came to this, but am furthermore wondering how this would be a closed form i.e. we don't even have x's in the sequence.

Thoughts would be very appreciated.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: By the way, your problem does not have a simple solution.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I think my answer seems fairly simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with the recursion for $a_n$ :
$$
a_n=(n-1)a_{n-2}+5
$$

---

Let $c_n=\dfrac{a_{2n}}{(2n-1)!!}$ and we get
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2n}&=(2n-1)a_{2n-2}+5\\
(2n-1)!!\,c_n&=(2n-1)!!\,c_{n-1}+5\\
c_n&=c_{n-1}+\frac5{(2n-1)!!}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2n}
&=(2n-1)!!\left(1+5\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(2k-1)!!}\right)\\
&=\left\lfloor(2n-1)!!\,\left(1+5\sqrt{\frac{e\pi}{2}}\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\right)\right\rfloor&&\text{for }n\ge3
\end{align}
$$

---

Let $c_n=\dfrac{a_{2n+1}}{(2n)!!}$ and we get
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2n+1}&=2na_{2n-1}+5\\
(2n)!!c_n&=(2n)!!c_{n-1}+5\\
c_n&=c_{n-1}+\frac5{(2n)!!}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2n+1}
&=(2n)!!\left(6+5\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(2k)!!}\right)\\
&=\left\lfloor(2n)!!\,\left(1+5\sqrt{e}\right)\right\rfloor&&\text{for }n\ge2
\end{align}
$$

---

Thus, for indices greater than $4$, we get the closed formulae
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2n}&=\left\lfloor c_{\text{even}}\,(2n-1)!!\right\rfloor&&\text{for }n\ge3\\
a_{2n+1}&=\left\lfloor c_{\text{odd}}\,(2n)!!\right\rfloor&&\text{for }n\ge2\\
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
c_{\text{even}}&=1+5\sqrt{\frac{e\pi}{2}}\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)&&=8.05343067321223998845412355710\\
c_{\text{odd}}&=1+5\sqrt{e}&&=9.24360635350064073424325393907\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

We have that $a_{n+1}=na_{n-1}+5$.

Define $A(z)$ as you did $\sum a_nz^n$. Multiply by $z^{n+1}$ and add for all $n$. We get

$$\sum a_{n+1}z^{n+1}=z^2\sum na_{n-1}z^{n-1}+5\sum z^{n+1}$$

which is

$$A(z)=z^2(zA(z))'+\frac{5z}{1-z}.$$

Useful to translate operations on the sequence to operations on the generating function it [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties).

**You may have to add a polynomial to the equation depending on the initial conditions, which I am not looking.**

Can you solve the differential equation?

There are [general procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Equation_with_variable_coefficients) to solve these types of differential equations.

Comment: @RGB Be careful with your indices of summation - you've lost some terms.

Comment: No.. I am not sure how (and haven't seen z-transforms before).  I am assuming $z^2(zA(z))' = \frac{z^{2}d(zA(z))}{dz} = z^{2}A(z) +z^{3} \frac{dA(z)}{dz}$  Then after some algebra I get $\frac{A(z)-z^{2}A(z)-5z/(1-z)}{z^3} = \frac{dA(z)}{dz}$  I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: This is a linear differential equation (with non-constant coefficients). The link at the bottom takes you to a wikipedia page that has some methods to solve it, to find $A(z)$ from it.

Answer (score 2):

Maple gets the following.  For $n$ odd.  In terms of the incomplete Gamma function.

$$
b_{{n}}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{\pi}}{{{2}^{n/2+1/2} \left( 10\,{{\rm e}^{1/2}}\sqrt {\pi }\;
\Gamma  \left( n/2+1 \right) {{\rm erf}\left(\sqrt {2}/2\right)}
\sqrt {2}+5\,\sqrt {2}n\Gamma  \left( n/2,1/2 \right) {{\rm e}^{1/2
}}\sqrt {\pi }\\-10\,{{\rm e}^{1/2}}\sqrt {\pi }\;\Gamma  \left( n/2+1
 \right) \sqrt {2}+4\,\Gamma  \left( n/2+1 \right)  \right) }}
$$

$b_1=1, b_3=18, b_5=115$

and for $n$ even
$$
b_{{n}}= \left( 5\,{{\rm e}^{1/2}}\Gamma  \left( n/2,1/2 \right) +
\Gamma  \left( n/2 \right)  \right) {2}^{n/2-1}n
$$

$b_0=0,b_2=12,b_4=68$

Comment: $b_1=1\cdot a_0=1$ by the given relation

Comment: Hmm ... somehow I used $a_0=0$. EDITING

Comment: @GEdgar: How come you got answer for the odd function only?

Comment: I get that $a_2=7$ and $a_4=33$ which would mean that $b_3=21$ and $b_5=165$.

Comment: I get $a_2=b_1+5=1+5=6$.  Right?

Comment: Aha! I see a problem... it is $a_n=(n-1)a_{n-2}+5$ I have to fix my answer.

Comment: added $n$ even, which Maple does only indirectly...

Comment: The OP wants a closed form for $a_n$. I have to convert $a_n$ to $b_n$ to compare :-)

Comment: @GEdgar, I get $a_1 = 6$ and $b_2 = 2*a_1 = 12$

Answer (score 0):

Start with $a_n = (n − 1) a_{n − 2} + 5$, and note that this is a first order linear recurrence in $b_n = a_{2 n + 1}$:

$$
b_{n + 1} = 2 n b_n + 5
$$

Summing factor is $\prod_{0 \le k \le n} 2 n = 2^n n!$:

$$
\frac{b_{n + 1}}{2^n n!} - \frac{b_n}{2^{n - 1} (n - 1)!}
  = \frac{5}{2^n n!}
$$

Sum for $1 \le k \le n$ to get:

$$
\frac{b_{n + 1}}{2^n n!} - b_1 = 5 \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{2^{-n}}{n!}
$$

The right hand side is (almost) $5 \left(e^{1/2} - 1 \right)$, so $a_{2 n + 1} = b_n \approx a_1 + 5 \cdot 2^{n - 1} (n - 1)! \left(e^{1/2} - 1\right)$