# How to prove that: $19.999<e^\pi-\pi<20$?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, approximation, real-numbers

> I would like to know how to prove 
>   $$e^\pi-\pi\sim 20.$$
>   More precisely, I want to show by using only mathematical tools that, 
>   $$19.999<e^\pi-\pi<20$$

---

I have checked with online  calculator and I got 
$$e^\pi-\pi\approx19.9990999792\sim 20.$$

I tried to use the Tyalor expansion for exponential
$$ e^\pi =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^n}{n!} = \pi +1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^n}{n!}$$
then, $$e^\pi -\pi =1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^n}{n!}$$
which is not easy to continue from here, since the factor $\pi^n$ is involved. Any idea?

Comment: Hello , see here .https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0016. Have a good day

Comment: @max8128 What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Seriously I went through that link I felt stupid

Comment: There is some information here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostInteger.html

Comment: For the lower bound, you need to approximate $\pi$ to at least $5$ decimal digits and then you need to sum terms of the exponential series at least to $n=14$. This is, in theory possible, but is going to be plain tedious...

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252823/integrals-for-rational-approximations-to-e-pi
and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604718/rational-series-representation-of-e-pi

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the iteration to calculate [Gelfond's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant):
$$k_0 = 1/\sqrt{2},\quad k_{n+1}={\frac {1-{\sqrt {1-k_{n}^{2}}}}
{1+{\sqrt {1-k_{n}^{2}}}}}$$
$$e^\pi =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{4}{k_{n+1}}\right)^{2^{-n}}$$

Within two iterations you should have (assuming you know $\pi$ to 5 or more digits and that you're willing to compute three square roots), that $e^\pi-\pi\approx 19.999$:

$$k_1=3-2\sqrt{2}$$
$$k_2=33+24\sqrt{2}-4\sqrt{140+99\sqrt{2}}$$
And:
$$\sqrt{4\over k_2} \approx 19.99926 + \pi$$

Comment: (+1) It might be interesting to expand this answer and explain *why* we may compute $e^\pi$ through a numerical algorithm that is reminiscent of the AGM mean for the computation of complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - I've actually been looking for the source of this series, and don't have access to the book mentioned as a source. Do you know how to derive it? If so, I'll ask a dedicated question

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - Here goes:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489586/origin-of-apidly-converging-series-for-e-pi