# Origin of rapidly converging sequence for $e^\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elliptic-integrals, experimental-mathematics

The following sequence converging to Gelfond's constant ($e^\pi$) is apparently mentioned (and originates?) in the book *"Mathematics by Experiment: Plausible Reasoning in the 21st Century."*, which I unfortunately do not have access to.
$$k_0 = 1/\sqrt{2},\quad k_{n+1}={\frac {1-{\sqrt {1-k_{n}^{2}}}}
{1+{\sqrt {1-k_{n}^{2}}}}}$$
$$e^\pi =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{4}{k_{n+1}}\right)^{2^{-n}}$$
How is this sequence and similar ones derived?

Comment: The algorithm above appears at page 137 of *Mathematics by Experiment*, but no proof is given there either.

Comment: Anyway, it is not difficult to guess that such algorithm is related to $e^{\pi K'/K}$ and to the fact that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is an elliptic singular value, hence it turns out to be a minor twist on the classical AGM algorithm for the computation of $K(k)$. I will write a detailed answer tomorrow, if no one comes before me. Time to sleep in Italy, have a good night.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in comments (to the question) from Jack d'Aurizio this is related to elliptic integrals. And based on the feedback received in comments to this answer I provide some background in the theory of elliptic integrals and theta functions. The details along with proofs are available in the linked blog posts.

---

Let $k\in(0,1)$ be the *elliptic modulus* and then we define *complementary modulus* $k'=\sqrt{1-k^{2}}$. Further the complete elliptic integrals of the first kind are defined by $$K(k)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}x}},\, K'(k)=K(k')\tag{1}$$ By the way the use of prime $(') $ here does not denote derivative.

Starting with a modulus $k$ we define a new modulus $l$ via *ascending Landen transformation* $$l=\frac{2\sqrt{k}}{1+k},\,k=\frac{1-l'}{1+l'},\, l>k\tag{2}$$ where $l'$ is complementary to $l$ ie $l'=\sqrt{1-l^{2}}$. [It can be proved with some effort](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/pi-and-the-agm-evaluating-elliptic-integrals.html) that $$K(l)=(1+k) K(k)$$ Using a little amount of algebra it can be seen that the relation between $l$ and $k$ is same as the relation between $k'$ and $l'$ and hence from the above equation we get $$K'(k) =(1+l') K'(l)=\frac{2K'(l)}{1+k}$$ and therefore from the last two equations we get $$\frac{K'(k)} {K(k)} =2\cdot\frac{K'(l)}{K(l)}\tag{3}$$ Corresponding to elliptic modulus $k$ we have another variable $q$ called *nome* defined by $q=\exp(-\pi K'(k) /K(k)) $ and it is possible to get an expression for $k$ in terms of $q$ via the use of [theta functions](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/10/the-magic-of-theta-functions.html). We have $$k=\frac{\vartheta_{2}^{2}(q)}{\vartheta_{3}^{2}(q)}\tag{4}$$ where $$\vartheta_{2}(q)=2q^{1/4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}q^{n(n+1)},\,\vartheta_{3}(q)=1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}}\tag{5}$$

---

The sequence $k_{n} $ in question is descending Landen sequence of elliptic moduli and using equation $(3)$ we have $$\frac{K'(k_{n+1})}{K(k_{n+1})}=2\cdot\frac{K'(k_{n})}{K(k_{n})},\, K'(k_{0})=K(k_{0})\tag{6}$$ The corresponding nomes $q_{n} =\exp(-\pi K'(k_{n}) /K(k_{n})) $ have a relation between them as $q_{n+1}=q_{n}^{2}$. Thus we can see that $$e^{-\pi}=q_{0}=(q_{n})^{2^{-n}}\tag{7}$$ Next also note that $q_{n} \to 0, k_{n} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and using $(4)$ we have the relation $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{k_{n}^{2}}{16q_{n}}= 1\tag{8}$$ (the above equation can also be proved without using the theory of theta function via [the fundamental asymptotic](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/12/elementary-approach-to-modular-equations-ramanujan-theory-2.html) $K'(k) =\log(4/k)+o(1)$ as $k\to 0^{+}$). The desired relation follows easily from $(7)$ and $(8)$ and the relation $k_{n} ^{2}=4k_{n+1}/(1+k_{n+1})^{2}$.

Comment: Do you think I understand anything of what you wrote ?

Comment: Thank you! Could add some more detail for those who aren't familiar with the topic? (e.g. What's a Landen sequence? How do we get the value of the limit?)

Comment: @reuns : I will add some more details, but let me know specific areas which you find need explanation.

Comment: @nbubis: will add more details, wait for sometime.

Comment: I can't even explain what I want explanations on, honestly this is just a mess of symbols without any explanation. In the theory of elliptic integrals and functions there is a lattice and an associated cubic polynomial with some special functions (and their inverse functions) attached to it.

Comment: @reuns - though I have no background in Elliptical function theory, I think the general outline is pretty clear. Maybe this page will help clear things up: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Here if $k_n$ is really the main sequence (defined by $k_0 =?,k_{n} ^{2}=4k_{n+1}/(1+k_{n})^{2}$ ? Why ?) then $q_n$ is a function of $k_n$ and the question is what property of it you are using.

Comment: @reuns: I have updated the answer with some details. We don't need elliptic function theory here. Some basic properties of elliptic integrals and theta functions are all we need here.

Comment: To the downvoter: I have updated my answer and perhaps you may reconsider your decision regarding the vote.

Comment: Thank you Paramanand! This is very clear and concise.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Did you see this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4460350/42969? The iteration looks a bit similar to this one, and the claimed limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} 4^n a_n = \frac1{8\pi}\Gamma\,^4\!\left(\frac1{4}\right)$ can also be expressed in terms of the elliptic integral $K$.

Comment: @MartinR: the claimed limit is equal to $2K^2(1/\sqrt{2})$ where $K(k) $ is defined as $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}}$. I will check formulas related to elliptic integrals to see we can do something about the linked question.