# Bounding $\int^{\infty}_{0} \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} \frac{dy}{1+y^2} \frac{\sinh(\pi x) \sinh(\pi y)}{\sinh(\pi (x+y))}$ close to $1$

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation

I've come across an integral that when numerically evaluated is quite close to $1$. The integral is in fact loosely related to a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804630/a-curious-coincidence-prod-limits-k-1-infty-left1-int-kk1-left-fr) that similarly was suspiciously close to a simple result.

$$I = \int^{\infty}_{0} \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} \frac{dy}{1+y^2} \frac{\sinh(\pi x) \sinh(\pi y)}{\sinh(\pi (x+y))} \approx 1.0088$$

While I'd be interested in an analytical answer to the integral, I suspect it might be tough to evaluate exactly. Instead, I'd like to see if there might be some appropriate series expansion or other approximation technique that could show that this integral is in fact close to $1$.

---

Here is a rough estimate that places $I$ in the right ballpark.

By rewriting $I$, we can note that:

$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{0} \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} \frac{dy}{1+y^2} \frac{(1-e^{-2 \pi x}) (1-e^{-2 \pi y})}{(1-e^{-2 \pi (x+y)})} <\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{0} \int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} \frac{dy}{1+y^2} $$

This means

$$I < \frac{\pi^2}{8} \approx 1.2337$$

However, I'm less confident about systematic ways to tighten this upper bound or to introduce lower bounds.

Comment: What tool did you use for comuting the integral ? With different CAS, I failed.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I found that the integral was most stable when I wrote it in the second form with decaying exponentials, and then Mathematica evaluated it without any flags.

Comment: It is effectivel spectacular.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm excited to hear why you say that :)

Comment: Just because I tried the second formulation ! Cheers :-)